# Why does node wait for a single promise, but not an array of promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

Consider this function which mocks querying a database, and returning some records after 2 seconds, via a Promise:

```
function query() {
  var recs = [1,2,3];
  return new Promise(r => setTimeout(() => r(recs), 2000))
}
```

If I add the following statement:

```
query().then(console.log);
```

and run the script the with node, it pauses 2 seconds, prints out the records, and returns, as expected.

On the other hand, if I replace that line with an array of the exact same promises:

```
Array(5).map(x => query().then(console.log));
```

The script returns immediately, and prints nothing.  Why does node wait for the single promise to return before exiting, but exit immediately when there's an array of 5 unresolved promises?

Comment: If you want to wait one resolved promise to execute another this post would like you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37578795/implementing-promise-series-as-alternative-to-promise-all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `Array(5).map(...` will never call the function passed to map. The reason is that map skips holes in the array. `Array(5)` returns what is called a sparse array, and has only empty slots but no actual content.

For more information about sparse arrays and how to turn them into dense arrays I would recommend [this excellent blog](http://www.2ality.com/2012/06/dense-arrays.html) post by Axel Rauschmayer.

Comment: ugh, i just forgot to call `fill`.  ty.

Comment: You can use Array.from({length : 5}, mapFunction);

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo, very nice, didn't know about that.